# How do I use Tapestry-Security?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tapestry, tynamo

I discovered Tapestry 5, quite recently, its clear separation between view and controller, the use of name standardization instead of XML made me go for it straight. Quite frankly I don't plan on changing but the documentation is just not enough for me.

The project I'm working on must be able to support several types of roles. I must allow users authentifications, the use of certains services according to their roles ans the access of url by their roles as well.

After some research I came across [Tapestry-Security](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-security+guide) which is part of the Tynamo project.

I want my Service layer to be totaly independant from my web application because I will then use it to implement web services and some others stuff. I do not feel like doing another identification system when the time comes.

My problem is that I do not see how use Tapestry-Security without using Tapestry.The example they show on Tapestry-Security guide is just not enough for me. I have a pretty rough idea, how it works.
However I do not know how I could use it outside the Tapestry 5.

How can I use Tapestry-Security without Tapestry 5 ?

I also do not understand the filter systems used in the AppModule class in Tapestry project.
Is there a document which explain the way AppModule works with the filter system ?

Is there someone which can explain me those things or point me in the right direction ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tapestry-Security is just a thin layer on top of the [Apache Shiro](http://incubator.apache.org/shiro/spring.html) project. It only provides:

- a way to configure Shiro via your Tapestry application module
- a set of Tapestry filters to do the actual security checks for Tapestry pages and actions
- [annotations](http://tynamo.org/constant/tapestry-security/apidocs/org/tynamo/shiro/extension/authz/annotations/package-summary.html) should you like to declare your security declaratively
- [components](http://tynamo.org/constant/tapestry-security/apidocs/org/tynamo/security/components/package-summary.html) to support conditional rendering in your `.tml` files

Underneath that layer, there is an ordinary instance of Shiro doing all the work, so you can access security (for example via the [SecurityUtils](http://incubator.apache.org/shiro/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/SecurityUtils.html) class) like you normally would if Tapestry wasn't involved at all.

*Edit based on comment:* So while you can use Shiro in any web application you use, Tapestry-Security is really just a wrapper for use with Tapestry. If you, however, have an app that includes Tapestry along with other servlets (such as a web service), you should be able to let Tapestry-Security do the initialization work.

*Concerning Tapestry filters:*  I'm afraid this isn't documented very well. Tapestry filters work very much like Servlet Filters, but as Tapestry is [implemented as a Servlet Filter itself](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/TapestryFilter.html), it has its own filter chain. Filters for Tapestry implement the [RequestFilter](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/RequestFilter.html) interface.

```
public class MyFilter implements RequestFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean service(final Request request, final Response response,
            final RequestHandler handler) throws IOException {
        ... //your code
        try {
            return handler.service(request, response);
        } finally {
            ... //your code
        }

    }
}
```

You can add them to the filter chain by contributing them in your application module:

```
public void contributeRequestHandler(
            final OrderedConfiguration<RequestFilter> configurations) {
    configuration.add("MyFilter", new MyFilter());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Does that mean that tapestry-security can be used without Tapestry achitecture but I would need to add Tapestry-Security filter in whatever application I use ? or that I should use Shiro in my service layer and then use Tapestry-Security in my web application to initialize it ?




I get the point on filter, I guess implementing the RequestFilter interface and adding it to the AppModule class by adding its contribute methods, allow me to extends Tapestry capabilites.

Comment: @lollancf37: I've updated my answer. About filters: Yes, that's what they are for.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand things much better now.